# Spring form select from a list of objects displayed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am displaying a list of objects in a spring form like below

```
    <form:form method="POST"  commandName="productlist">
    <table>
    <c:forEach var="product" items="${productlist}">
    <tr id=${product.id}><td>${product.name}</td>  
    </tr>    
   </c:forEach>
   </table>
   </form:form>
```

Now, I want a checkbox in front of each product in jsp so that user can select any of the product and selected list of product goes to the controller for further processing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the form backing object as this:

```
public class ProductForm {
private List<String> productList;//checkbox values to be shown
private String[] selProductList;//selected checkbox values available for processing
//other properties
...
//getters and setters
}
```

Now you can define the `checkbox` as this:

```
<form:form action="/productAction" method="post" modelAttribute="productform">
<form:checkboxes items="${productform.productList}" path="selProductList" />
...
</form>
```

On submission of this `form`, the selected checkbox values will be available to you through `selProductList` array.

Comment: Thanks Debojit, I tried with List<Product> instead of List<String> in the class ProductForm. After that page started displaying toString content of each product with checkbox option on the output. but when submitting the page after selecting the few products, it gave the following exception  org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'productList' on field 'selProductList': rejected value [productId :13name :dhanush]

Comment: Also wondering if it is right approach to create a model class for every form, not sure but might be that I will have to create a number of model classes then

Comment: i don't see any need to use `List<Product>` instead of `List<String>` to show the checkbox values, because the values to be shown to the user are strings only. And it is not a bad idea to use one form backing object for your `forms`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a checkbox inside td

```
<form:form method="POST"  commandName="productlist">
    <table>
    <c:forEach var="product" items="${productlist}">
    <tr id=${product.id}><td><form:checkbox path=""/>${product.name}</td>  
    </tr>    
   </c:forEach>
   </table>
   </form:form>
```

see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/monicka2479/8WF4r/)